# Get server JSON response as a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nscfstring

I'm trying to get server response `NSData` into `NSDictionary` but it returns following `NSCFString`.

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary* jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

And can't access data using `objectForKey`.
Give me a way to get this response as a `NSDictionary` or conversion mechanism. Cannot get anything `NSJSONSerialization` with `kNilOptions` returns `nil`.

Comment: Please check what type does the method returns.

Comment: @iPeter It's NSCFString

Comment: Most likely `data` doesn't actually represent a JSON dictionary. Create a string from `data` and see what you are actually getting.

Comment: @rmaddy using NSJSONReadingAllowFragments it returns correct JSON.

Comment: That contradicts everything you've stated. You state that at the moment, `jsonDict` is really an `NSCFString` and not an `NSDictionary`. Therefore `data` does not represent a JSON dictionary. If you convert `data` to a string and print it out, you will be able to see the actual JSON you are getting. Then you can figure out how to get the correct JSON from wherever you are getting the data from.

Comment: Print `data`, then we could understand what your issue, because now we don't understand.

Comment: yes, show DATA what you receive in response.

Comment: NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

Answer (score 0):

According to this question can't serialize with `NSJSONSerialization` with option `kNilOptions`.

So first we need to get above serialized JSON as a `NSString` and then convert it into NSData again. Then you can convert it back to `NSDictionary` with `kNilOptions`.

```
NSString* jsonString = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization jsonData options:0 error:nil];
```

Comment: I don't think this will work !! , If Data is itself string data then any of the option not work

Comment: Nope. It's NSData. We have to converted.

Answer (score 0):

After using NSJSONSerialization for a while I got more problems than solutions while parsing the data.

I would kindly advice you to use SBJson library which may be found as cocoapod and serves me well for many projects without any issues for many many years

E.g. [https://cocoapods.org/pods/SBJson][1]